# Creating a new dataframe in python based on calculations of existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In Table given in the top, I have this data of around 50000 lines.

[image: Top Table]

In the bottom table, my desired data output.

[image: Bottom Table]

First, calculation is my FLOWRATE in which, I want to count the number of values contained in a given TIMESTEP. For eg. calculation at TIMESTEP = 5200 FLOWRATE = 100 (1 * 100) (as only one atom id '75' is present. 100 here is my constant multiplier factor for all FLOWRATE values)

Second, I want to calculate the my MASS FLOW RATE for a TIMESTEP which is the product of FLOW RATE calculated above and correspoding mass of the id. For eg. TIMESTEP 5200 FLOWRATE 100 MASS FLOWRATE = 100 * 0.895253 = 89.5253. If more than one 'id' is present in a given TIMESTEP, then MASS FLOW RATE = FLOW RATE * sum of MASS FLOW RATE of ids. For eg. for TIMESTEP 5500, FLOWRATE 200 (TWO ids are there 86 and 325), MASS FLOW RATE  306.4898 i.e FLOW RATE * (sum of masses of id 86 and 325) = 200 * (0.768832 + 0.763617)

I have tried it coding using the below approach:

```
tstep = 5200
for row in df_intermediate.iterrows():
    df_new = df_intermediate[df_intermediate['TIMESTEP'] == 'tstep']
    df_final["TIMESTEP"] = df_new["tstep"]
    df_final["FLOW RATE"] = df_new[len["id"] * 100
    df_final["MASS FLOW RATE"] =  df_final["FLOW RATE"] * df_new["mass"]
    tstep = tstep + 100
```

But not able to generate my desired output table

Comment: Please check your code indentation. I have edited it for you, but make sure it's correct.

Comment: How can I average the FR and MFR based on 10 values of TIMESTEP like this:

Comment: I have given you an answer that matches your expected output. If you have any follow-up questions, you should create a new post. I have no idea what your comment means.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby`:

```
output = df.groupby("TIMESTEP").agg(FLOW_RATE=("id", "count"), MASS_FLOW_RATE=("mass", "sum"))
output["FLOW_RATE"] = output["FLOW_RATE"].mul(100)
output["MASS_FLOW_RATE"] = output["MASS_FLOW_RATE"].mul(output["FLOW_RATE"])

>>> output
          FLOW_RATE  MASS_FLOW_RATE
TIMESTEP                           
5200            100         89.5253
5400            100         68.3110
5500            200        306.4898
5600            100         93.1666
5700            100         79.4396
6100            100         78.2639
```